# View [projects.index] not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://View%20[projects.index]%20not%20found.), but I'm getting this error message:

```
View [projects.index] not found.
```

When I access the /projects url.
This is the structure of my resources/views:

```
errors [folder]
vendor [folder]
create.blade.php
show.blade.php
welcome.blade.php
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Where's your index.php file? And is the projects folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i cannot open your link, but your error because you don't have file `index.blade.php` in your view folder.

just create new file `index.blade.php` in your view folder and it will work

[image: file folder]

Answer (score 0):

You must have an `index.php` file in the `projects` folder if you're calling it that way.

So it's `view('folder.file')`, except the `.blade.php` part.